# Referencing a object of TableViewCell A in TableViewCell B

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a `UILabel` in my `TableViewCell_A`. When I change a value in my `TableViewCell_B` I want to change the text of the `UILabel` in `TableViewCell_A`. How might a reference a cell that is already created. I don't know how it could be passed in as `self` and I've tried using `var cell = MySettingsViewController().settingsTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(2)` which is obviously incorrect. Someone please help me.

Comment: You should never try to reference other cells directly as 1) they are re-used and 2) the information in them should be held in a model (using MVC design). So update your model that supplies information to your `UITableViewCell`s and then reload the cells at the `indexPath`s you want to update.

Comment: @RoboticCat This may be a dumb question but what is the call for reloading a single cell?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. You need to use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [AnyObject], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` (link to documentation:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) where `indexPaths` is an array containing `NSIndexPath` objects (or in your case a single `NSIndexPath` object) and `UITableViewRowAnimation` is probably `.None`.

Comment: @RoboticCat I tried calling it from `MySettingsViewController().settingsTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(index: 2)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` and I get an error saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` What is the proper way to call it?

Comment: That's not how I would expect it to be called...I would expect something more along the lines of `let idx = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0); self.settingsTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([idx], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)`. Code not tested obviously. If you get more `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` then you need to check `idx` and `self.settingsTableView` are non-nil.

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass in my `UITableView` to the `TableViewCellA` upon initializing it so that I could access `.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` which reloaded `TableViewCellB` with the new values.